# Less CSS - How to return value in viewport with (vw)

Tags: less

The Less percentage function returns value in (%) - wow!

```
element {
  width: percentage(700 / 1400);
}
```

will compile to:

```
element {
  width: 50%;
}
```

What would be the best way or syntax to get the value in (vw) so the style will compile to:
(bare in mind that the division function needs to be used. (700 / 1400))

```
element {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to achieve the expected output would be to multiply the value by 100vw. This would be the most meaningful and easily understandable method.

```
a{
  width: 700/1400 * 100vw;
}
```

The below method of using [`unit()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit) function works too but I wouldn't really recommend it.

<strike>One of the primary reasons why I wouldn't recommend it is because I am not sure if that is **supposed** to work as it does. The `unit()` function is supposed to take a number as its first parameter and add the units to it but a percentage value is not exactly a number and this may not work in future versions depending on how the Less core team view it</strike>.

I read the docs and it seems like the first parameter can be a number with or without a dimension but I still wouldn't recommend it because the earlier method is far more easier to understand than the usage of functions.

```
b{
  width: unit(percentage(700/1400), vw);
}
```